# Naming Parameters in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters, arguments

I'm using Codecademany (I'm a beginner.) and I came across a problem that had to do with naming parameters. Ther is no error and it does what I want it to but I noticed that in line 19 it names the parameter `variance`, a previously defined variable. What I want to know is, what happens when a function calls its parameter and a variable by the same name. Does it call the variable or the argument? How does it decide? And how can I choose which one?

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def print_grades(grades_input):
  for grade in grades_input:
    print grade

def grades_sum(scores):
  return sum(scores)

def grades_average(grades_input):
  return grades_sum(grades_input) / float(len(grades_input))

def grades_variance(scores):
  variance = 0
  for score in scores:
    variance += (grades_average(scores) - score) ** 2
  return variance / len(scores)

def grades_std_deviation(variance):
  return variance ** 0.5
```

Comment: I don't think this would be an issue, as the _scope_ of the `variance` variable is limited to the previous function.  In other words, from the point of view of Python, `variance` has not been defined previously.

Comment: The variable will be used in the scope of the function instead of the function argument. The Python standard indicate this semantics. You can control it by naming the parameters and variables as different names within the function.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is a local name that is bound to a object as part of the call.  If a function parameter name is the same as a global name, then within the function, the name refers to the parameter, not the global.

```
a = 0
def f(a):
    print(a)
f(1)  # prints 1, not 0
```

Local names within difference functions that are not nested within each other, with with `variance` in your code, cannot interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

This would not matter because the scope of the variable `variance` would be contained within the scope of the function. This means that once the function's use ends, the variable disappears. If you did have something like this:

```
x = 5
y = 6

def myFunction(x):
    return x + y

myFunction(2)
```

The function would return as 8, not 11 because it takes priority over the scope.

Answer (score 0):

`variance` is defined **inside** a function, in this case **`grades_variance`**, so when an argument is called `variance` again in the **`grades_std_deviation`**, they don't conflict at all.

This is called ***scope*** and in plain English means: **Where** you can use that variable, without getting errors such as conflicts with other vars that have the same name, or the interpreter telling you it doesn't exist, because it's **outside** the scope from where it was defined.